# Loading a .mov format video in a Nuxt app (for Safari)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, safari, nuxt.js, .mov

In my Nuxt app I'm loading a video of the `.webm` format which works as expected. As a fallback for Safari I would like to load a `.mov` formatted video:

```html
<video>
  <!-- Safari -->
  <source src="~/assets/videos/video.mov" type="video/mov" />
  <!-- other browsers -->
  <source src="~/assets/videos/video.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

However, it seems that this format is not supported with the default webpack config, this is what I get:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders (Source code omitted for this binary file)

The question is how should a loader for this specific file type (`mov`) configured?
I couldn't find anything helpful in the mentioned link, nor on the web in general.

Please check this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-mov-format-example-qkg0y) to see a reproduction of this issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you looked how to have a specific loader for Webpack? There are some tutorials here and there.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? If you did let me know how, please.

Comment: @Eduardo, I ended up using the mov formatted videos with a `.mp4` extension seems to work .

Comment: If you don't mind please upvote the question, so it should get some attention.

Comment: @kissu, see please my comment one before the previous one, I was referring to Eduardo

Comment: Shaya Ulman, thanks for answering! But that option does not work for me because I need exactly ```.mov``` container due to its transparency support.

Comment: The problem is solved. That's how my ```build``` section of ```nuxt.config.js``` looks like:
```build: {
    extend (config) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(mov)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[path][name].[ext]',
          esModule: false
        }
      })
    }
  }```


I know that the code looks ugly in comments but hope that would help someone.

Comment: @Eduardo post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem. All we need is to extend `webpack`'s config. That's how my `build` section of `nuxt.config.js` looks like:

```js
build: {
  extend (config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(mov)$/i,
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[path][name].[ext]',
        esModule: false
      }
    })
  }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks! seems to be the right solution.

Comment: You are welcome!) Hope that someone would find that useful :)

Comment: How will be the solution for `Nuxt3`?

Comment: @kike guess you use vite as a bundler, so you need to google how to implement the same thing using vite.